# jQuery modal multiple elements same class used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please help me with a plugin I found. It works great but I want to modify it a little but my javascript/jQuery knowledge is basically zero.

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay/
```

First I made this change `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` so it works on the latest jQuery version, the script is set for version 1.8.2..

I only want to use the tooltip and to make a simple pop up/maximize image tool.

This is how far I got after, I'm ashamed to say, 3 sleepless nights.

For the tooltip

```
<input class="my_tooltip_open" type="submit" value="Tooltip1"></input>
<div id="my_tooltip" class="well">
    <a href="#" class="my_tooltip_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    <h4>Tooltip example 1</h4>
    <p>Tooltip content 1 will be positioned relative to the opening link.</p>
</div>

<input class="my_tooltip_open" type="submit" value="Tooltip2"></input>
<div id="my_tooltip" class="well">
    <a href="#" class="my_tooltip_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    <h4>Tooltip example 2</h4>
    <p>Tooltip content 2 will be positioned relative to the opening link.</p>
</div>
```

And this is the function:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("[id^=my_tooltip]").popup({
        type: 'tooltip',
        vertical: 'bottom',
        transition: '0.3s all 0.1s',
        tooltipanchor: $('.my_tooltip_open')
    });

});
</script>
```

I know it looks stupid, i should've used CLASS instead of ID but this is the only way i could make it to work and display the tooltips. The only problem is that it always shows the last tooltip.

It should probably and logically look like this.

```
 <input class="my_tooltip_open" type="submit" value="Tooltip1"></input>
    <div class="my_tooltip" class="well">
        <a href="#" class="my_tooltip_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
        <h4>Tooltip example 1</h4>
        <p>Tooltip content 1 will be positioned relative to the opening link.</p>
    </div>

    <input class="my_tooltip_open" type="submit" value="Tooltip2"></input>
    <div class="my_tooltip" class="well">
        <a href="#" class="my_tooltip_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
        <h4>Tooltip example 2</h4>
        <p>Tooltip content 2 will be positioned relative to the opening link.</p>
    </div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      [SOMETHING MAGICAL HERE LIKE (this).next !??!]('.my_tooltip').popup({
            type: 'tooltip',
            vertical: 'bottom',
            transition: '0.3s all 0.1s',
            tooltipanchor: $('.my_tooltip_open')
        });

    });
    </script>
```

And for the image maximize and gallery part i ended up with this

```
    <img src="img1.jpg" class="my_popup_open" width="200px" height="200px;" style="cursor:zoom-in;" />     
    <div id="my_popup">
    <img src="img1.jpg"/>  
<button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
      </div>    
      <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $('#my_popup').popup();
        });
      </script>
```

And this is what i was aiming for:

```
 <img src="img1.jpg" class="my_popup_open" width="200px" height="200px;" style="cursor:zoom-in;" />     
    <img src="img2.jpg" class="my_popup_open" width="200px" height="200px;" style="cursor:zoom-in;" />   
  <img src="imgn.jpg" class="my_popup_open" width="200px" height="200px;" style="cursor:zoom-in;" />

  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#my_popup').popup();
      (a wonderful thing called a close button somewhere on the right up.)
      (another magical thing called "next" and "prev button" if there are more pictures)
    });
  </script>
```

If i click on next or prev it should go to the next or prev pictures if they exist. 
Also this function already exists on this plugin, if you click on the demo on "Fade" example you see a button there "Next example".

I really like this plugin it seems very fast and simple (for who knows javascript, I can't even use it right).

I know that I'm asking for a lot of help but maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for all your time.

Comment: `[SOMETHING MAGICAL HERE LIKE (this).next !??!]('.my_tooltip') ` Maybe this "magical" is https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ ?

Comment: I dont see a question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change set popup to element.
change your java script code with give code.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

$('.my_tooltip').each(function(){
       $(this).popup({
            type: 'tooltip',
            vertical: 'bottom',
            transition: '0.3s all 0.1s',
            tooltipanchor: $('.my_tooltip_open')
        });
});
    });

Comment: It doesnt work. I've replaced with your code and changed from ID to CLASS. Now the buttons dont work.